# In R, fill in the main dataframe with data from two different data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

For my project, I am researching things related to covid from various part of the world. This particular code researches Colorado.

Currently, I have three dataframes: "main" where everything will come together, "cases" that has the number of cases from a certain source, and "death" which has the number of deaths from the same source.

Due to the nature of my work I cannot reveal all the info I have on each dataframes, but they look like the following:

Currently, cases and deaths are in the following format

| Column names | data format |
| --- | --- |
| category | str |
| date | int |
| metric | str |
| value | int |
| location_id | int |
| location | str |

I want the values from both the cases and deaths dataframes to fill in the main dataframe. I want it to look something like the following

| Column names | data format |
| --- | --- |
| nid | int (something I will later fill in futher down the research) |
| location_id | int (from either the cases or deaths df) |
| location | str (from either the cases or deaths df) |
| date | int (from either the cases or deaths df) |
| deaths | int(value from deaths df) |
| deaths_measure | str (metric from deaths df) |
| cases | int (value form cases df) |
| hospitalizations | int (something I will later fill in futher down the research) |
| hospitalizations_measure | str (something I will later fill in futher down the research) |
| ICU | int (something I will later fill in futher down the research) |
| ICU_measure | str (something I will later fill in futher down the research) |

All three dataframes are here right now, with main df only consisting of column names.

Comment: Please make a less abstract example with some toy data und your expected output based on that data.

Comment: dput() the dataframes with some toy data, and describe the dataframe you expect.

Comment: If you have a structural programming question, there is no need to include any confidential information. But you should provide *something*, as it will be dramatically easier for people to give relevant assistance if they can use fake data you provide rather than guess about it.